# MySQL Workbench export error

Tags: mysql, import, export, comments, mysql-workbench

I designed a mysql database with Mysql Workbench and exported it as SQL commands. Then executed them on phpmyadmin. This is what happened:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Disable',
  `tabeiat` TINYINT NULL COMMENT 'Disable',
  `Khedmat` TINYINT NULL' at line 17
```

What's the problem with comments? Are they supported?

```
PHP Version 5.3.29
MySQL Version   5.5.40-cll
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created multiple line Persian comment in workstation that added an infected character in the commands.
This is the generated code:

[image]

And this weird character generated sql error :)

Comment: That's a question or rather an addition to your question. Why do you post it as answer then? Please amend your question and delete the answer or the moderators will do it.